# Inserting realtime data into Bigquery with a file on compute engine?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm downloading realtime data into a csv file on Google's Compute Engine instance and want to load this file into Bigquery for realtime analysis.

Is there a way for me to do this without first uploading the file to Cloud Storage?

I tried this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery but since my file isnt in JSON, this fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool)?  You can upload CSVs from it.

Comment: Is there a streaming data load option too? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Why do you need to stream it? Just upload the file using the `bq` command line tool.